# A question on number of elements in a set

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

I am trying questions in permutations and combinations from an assignment and I was unable to solve this question.

Let D be a set of tuples $(w_{1} ,..., w_{10}  )$ , where $w_{i} \in \{1,2,3\}$ , $1\leq i\leq  10$ and $w_{i}+w_{i+1} $ is an even number for each $i$ with $1\leq i \leq  9$  is .

Then number of elements in D are ?

Attempt: $1$ st elements can be chosen in $3$ ways. If element chosen is $1$ or $3$ then rest of elements can be chosen in $2^{9} $ ways. If $2$ is chosen then rest of elements can be chosen in $1$ ways.

So I got the total $3\times2^{9}+ 1$  ways.

But that's not correct as answer is $2^{10}  +1$ .

Can someone please tell what mistake I am making.

Comment: I would say your reasoning is correct so I can't understand how you got your result.

Comment: Why do you multiply by 3 at the beginig?

Comment: I edit your post to improve the formatting.  Please check that I haven't accidentally changed the meaning.  Just put one `$` at the beginning of any math expression and

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say your reasoning is correct so I can't understand how you got your result.

If the first element is $1$ then you have $N_1=2^9$ possibilities as you said.

If the first element is $2$ then you have $N_2=1$ possibilities as you said.

If the first element is $3$ then you have $N_3=2^9$ possibilities as you said.

So just sum them up!

$$N=N_1+N_2+N_3 = 2^9+1+2^9 = 2\times 2^9 + 1 = 2^{10}+1$$

Answer (score 1):

Because you must get an even number when you sum two consecutive numbers you either get all odd numbers or all even numbers.

If you start with a 2, then you must get all twos because if you add $1$ or $3$ to $2$ you get an odd number.

Likewise, if you start with an odd number then all subsequent numbers must be odd. There are $2^{10}$ ways to get a sequence of $1$s and $3$s and there is $1$ way to get a sequence of all $2$s so there are $2^{10}+1$ possible sequences.

Answer (score 0):

So you have either $2$ or $1,3$ as first character. So there should be $$2\times 2^9$$ for the ones in which you have **odd digits** and just one string i.e., $22\cdots 2$ for the **even digits**. So $\underbrace{2\cdot 2^9}_{\text{odd}}+\underbrace{1}_{\text{even}}=2^{10}+1$ the problem is that you are giving the $2$ the possibilities of the $3$ and $1$ which is false.